# How to access My main menu using navigation based application in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am started  navigation based application.   how can i access  from Uitableview  to  second menu ( xib ).any sample

Answer (score 2):

if you mean directly going to the main view of the navigation controller, then use the popToRootViewController method